# What test is most appropriate if you're interested in an interaction, but have more variables than samples

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value, interaction, partial-least-squares

I would love to get some advice regarding the following please!

I have a dataset (n = 99) that comprises of:

- Composite scores for 7 different cognitive domains
- Measures of 934 lipid species, which can be summed into 27 subclasses
- Cardiorespiratory fitness measured as VO2max (which I've also categorised as low/high
  in a new variable called "fitnessCategory")

I am interested in how an individual's fitness and lipids can impact cognitive function, but I'm not sure what the best statistical approach would be. I've considered the following:

1. Performing multiple linear regression analyses (cognition ~ lipids * fitnessCategory + covariates), and looping through all 7 cognitive domains and 27 lipid subclasses, but then I'm faced with the issue of adjusting for multiple comparisons. In this situation, would I be adjusting for 7 x 27 comparisons? I'm also only interested in the model if the interaction between lipids * fitnessCategory is significant, so would I be adjusting the p-value of the interactions or the overall model? I'm also unsure if I need to adjust in the first place as my lipids aren't truly independent of each other (they are highly correlated as many belong to similar overarching classes and differ only by 1 carbon or 1 hydroxyl group).
2. Performing a PLS, but then I'm not sure how to incorporate the interaction between lipids and fitness. The only way that I can see this happening is if I perform a PLS-DA (Y = fitnessCategory, X = all lipids), but then my sample size reduces significantly (~40-50 per group) and results in uneven group sizes. I also don't know how to control for multiple confounding factors e.g. sex/age (F and 70+ tend to be in the lower fitness group), is this something that an O-PLS-DA can account for?

Any and all advice/tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I'm a statistics novice, so I apologise if I'm asking a really basic question. Please feel free to state the obvious in your answers as if I have no prior knowledge!

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from some [statistical rethinking](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus).

Answer (score 13):

You have far too few observations and far too many predictors to reach conclusions. Whatever you do, you will be chasing noise, even if you correct for multiple comparisons and regularize, unless there is a truly *massive* signal in your data. You could focus on no more than four predictors (better only one or two) as motivated by biological theory. Or run many separate "analyses" *and label the results clearly as being exploratory*, because any "results" would *urgently* need to be replicated (and likely won't hold up under replication).

Comment: Consistent with Stephan’s answer, the hopeless of analyses on N < p data is studied [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata) with simple simulations.  Heavy use of data reduction (unsupervised learning) may be the only hope.  Reduce the dimensionality of the data (in a way that is masked to associations with response variables) to what the sample size can support analyzing.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, they're very helpful! I think I will try the "One-at-a-Time Bootstrap Feature Selection" method and see how I go